# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find libhunspell-linux-x86-64.so in the filesystem nor in the classpath

Tags: java, linux, gate, hunspell, languagetool

I am working on GATE tool and trying to process text in different language. I am using languageTool.jar. The processing of german and english is working fine. During the processing of french in GATE it is showing the below error.

```
Exception in thread "ApplicationViewer1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find libhunspell-linux-x86-64.so in the filesystem nor in the classpath
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'hunspell-linux-x86-64': libhunspell-linux-x86-64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at org.languagetool.rules.spelling.hunspell.Hunspell.<init>(Hunspell.java:99)
    at org.languagetool.rules.spelling.hunspell.Hunspell.getInstance(Hunspell.java:68)
    at org.languagetool.rules.spelling.hunspell.Hunspell.getInstance(Hunspell.java:54)
    at org.languagetool.rules.spelling.hunspell.HunspellRule.init(HunspellRule.java:169)
    at org.languagetool.rules.spelling.SpellingCheckRule.resetIgnoreTokens(SpellingCheckRule.java:107)
    at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.setIgnoreWords(JLanguageTool.java:366)
    at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.reInitSpellCheckIgnoreWords(JLanguageTool.java:395)
    at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.disableRule(JLanguageTool.java:379)
    at com.cognicor.LanguageToolCreator.sourceLanguageTool(LanguageToolCreator.java:139)
    at com.cognicor.MultilingualModule.execute(MultilingualModule.java:331)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.runComponent(SerialController.java:225)
    at gate.creole.SerialController.executeImpl(SerialController.java:157)
    at gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController.executeImpl(SerialAnalyserController.java:238)
    at gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController.execute(SerialAnalyserController.java:129)
    at gate.util.Benchmark.executeWithBenchmarking(Benchmark.java:291)
    at gate.gui.SerialControllerEditor$RunAction$1.run(SerialControllerEditor.java:1706)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My system is 64 bit. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What OS? Did you install `libhunspell-dev`? A prerequirement of that library?

Comment: @cricket_007 OS is Ubuntu 14.04 . Currently I am using [languagetool.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlanguagetoolcore27jar.htm) 
 which I have kept in the lib folder of GATE. hunspell folder is available inside the languagetool. I didnt install libhunspell-dev separately.

Comment: The JAR file doesn't include the `.so` binary library, probably, as the error says

Comment: I solved it. Last day I tried including libhunspell-linux-x86-64.so file in the lib folder of gate and it works.